# How should I offer Friday prayers if the mosque is far way from where I live?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

I have migrated from my home city, to join an engineering college as an undergrade which is a days travel from my hometown. The question I want to ask is that the college is located in an area where there are no nearby masjids (mosque) and I have not offered Friday prayers for the last two weeks. What should I do about it?

Comment: Try to identify other Muslims and ask them if they would like to join you for Friday prayer, you may find that they may already have arranged for this

Comment: What if they have n't?I already told some people but they just they just said nothing.I would still keep looking but what if i could find none,then do i have to offer it on my own.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on the topic, but I at least know that congregation is made up of at least two people, i.e. if you find at least one other person willing to join with for Friday prayers, then problem solved! Post your questions on other sites, IslamQA is really good in offering answers to such issues, let us know if you come across something somewhere else :)

Comment: You have many possibilities: Pray 4 rak'a dhohr  or find other people and pray it where you are in congregation or go to the mosque that prays jumu'ah your efforts will be rewarded